# How to automatically retrieve current adword spend from google

Tags: php, xml, curl, google-api

Does anyone know a guide or tutorial into how to access the Google adwords reports? I'm trying to pull in to my application the advertising spend per day (current to the time of checking or last Google update).  I can't quite find the API docs or methods **for getting the spend**.  Does anyone know of any good tutorials? Or can you point me in the right direction? Ideally dev should be in php :)

**UPDATE**

Using the API is er....at a cost. I'm ideally looking for a way to not have to pay for it! So if there is no "backend" way of doing it for free, then scraping the front end is a possibility I guess...

**UPDATE 2**

Ignore the above, the cost is so minimal, an API call is enough. But I still can't find the API method to get current or previous spend....

Comment: You can do a thousand API calls for 0.25$USD. Let say you were going to check every day the amount spent, that 25 cents would last you almost three years. Are you really that cheap?

Comment: Every day is too little, it would almost be once a min, due to the high traffic/advertising spend/conversions the system needs to be in place to balance everything out almost in real time. once a min is 525600 calls a year. Hmmm thats $135 a year. That's nothing. Ok i guess an API call isn't too bad. But i still can't find in the docs how to get current day (and previous spend)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at http://google-apility.sourceforge.net?

The query you want I think is [this one](http://google-apility.sourceforge.net/reference.html#campaign-getCampaignStats%28%24startDate%2C+%24endDate%29) (includes cost data).

Answer (score 2):

Let us [google](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/) that for you...

Comment: Well, you didn't mention in your question that you had already ruled out the API, so the sarcasm was somewhat in order. :)

Comment: placing a rather lame link to the api doc as an answer for a specific function is just acting like a dick

Comment: The art of asking a question includes giving adequate context for your question.  I intended to follow up with more details, but something else came up in the 'real world' and I didn't finish investigating, so I apologize.